# How did the Voth get into the Delta quadrant?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Memory Alpha doesn't explain this at all - just acknowledges that the Voth did indeed originate from Earth.  I would assume a spacecraft of some sort was essential, but this leaves open multiple options.  Eg, does that mean the Voth actually were the first earth species to invent the warp-drive if they used a warp-capable ship, or did they travel via an asteroid or something like that?  My question **is *how* did the Voth get into the Delta quadrant in the first place - did they use a warp-capable spaceship, or a spaceship at all?**  (I don't know if there's some reference in a novel or something)

Comment: Pure speculation: We know from The Chase that "thousands of years ago" there was a species alone in this galaxy. They spread their DNA across the galaxy in the hope to populate it. Giving the time-frame... the Vorth might be the first who came from this. The First Species was space-faring. Maybe they were so happy to have found new friends they took the Vorth there and gave Earth the chance to bear another species.

Comment: @Einer although pure speculation, it is quite logical (to quote a phrase)

Comment: They probably had warp and simply fell into a wormhole. We know that there's at least one near Federation Space that leads directly to the Delta Quadrant,

Comment: @Richard That wormhole is unstable: It only sometimes leads there and it is speculated that soon maybe both ends will become unstable. But as you said: There are many wormholes.

Comment: @Einer - it was becoming more unstable, the implication being that in the far past it was more stable.

Comment: The end of the Cretaceous period was 66 million years ago, and the Voth are less than 70 million light-years from Earth.  It's _almost_ reasonable that they didn't even need Warp drive, wormholes, or any other shortcuts to get there.

Comment: The lack of evidence of their civilisation (in the Alpha Quadrant) suggests they were transported wholesale rather than travelling the long way around.

Comment: Correction to my prior comment (the joys of commenting immediately after waking up):  The end of the Cretaceous period was 66 million years ago, and the Voth are less than 70 _thousand_ light-years from Earth. It's _completely_ reasonable that they didn't need Warp drive, wormholes, or any other shortcuts to get there.

Comment: @Richard Except that the Iconians also left very little evidence they were around

Comment: @Izkata - Except a whole bunch of technology and numerous archaeological sites, you mean?

Comment: @Richard The Federation had no proof of their existence until TNG-era

Comment: @Izkata - That's not true, they had no **definitive** proof but they had come across *legends* about them as "demons of air and darkness", "capable of appearing out of nowhere", etc etc.

Comment: @Richard A species that hopped into their generational spaceship (or even fleet thereof), pointed themselves toward the Delta Quadrant (for whatever reason), and just fired up the engines wouldn't leave any evidence of any kind behind on any planet but the one they left -- the very one where Chekotay speculated that their home had been an isolated island now lost to the bottom of the oceans, effectively concealing every trace of their existence until now.

Comment: @Kromey - It defies belief that they wouldn't leave any evidence on the planets they passed along the way.

Comment: @Richard Actually, it would defy belief if they *had* -- passing a planet by in your spaceship leaves no evidence behind, not least because "passing by" is still in real terms many many many *many* light-years distant (space is *very big*, after all). To leave evidence on a planet, they'd have to stop, get out, dink around and then leave behind bodies, artifacts, etc., only some of which would survive the next million-ish years to be discovered by later species; if they didn't stop and get out (or if they practiced "leave no trace" camping guidelines), there's no way to leave evidence behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Voth are capable of high-warp capabilities above the standard warp factor speed (1 - 9.99), technically they did not use the warp drive to propell them across the galaxy as anything above Warp 10 is defined as anywhere in the universe.

It can be concluded that they may have come across a wormhole however that would be unlikely as they would need to move a whole species within a certain timeframe before the wormhole is deemed unstable and collapses.

This is pure speculation as I have failed to find any sources containing this data, they created a propulsion similar to the slipstream drive or the transwarp drive.

[Source 1](http://www.star-fleet.com/ed/warp-chart.html)
 - Maximum warp velocity across the series

[Source 2](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Quantum_slipstream_drive) - Quantum slipstream and the similarities of the concept relative to the Borg transwarp drive.

[Source 3](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/False_Profits) - Wormhole the Ferengi used to travel between Alpha Quadrant and the Delta Quadrant.

[Source 4](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Voth) - Voth's past, evolving technologically faster and becoming superior but leaving to avoid destruction.

Comment: Welcome to scifi.stackExchange! Though you thoughts are very plausible, it's alway better to back them up with canon-source. Speculation is fine, but for an answer it should be supported by some sources.

Comment: Shall do that now.

Comment: Agreed. The question is asking for canon sources confirming the origin of the voth, not pure speculation. A good rule of thumb is 'back it up or leave it out'.

Comment: This is a good answer. I must admit, however, that I think the idea of a generation ship is more believable; it seems odd that the Voth would have such advanced technology 66 million years ago, then not advance much afterwards. It's more likely that they escaped Earth in a generation ship, pointed it at the Delta Quadrant for some reason - maybe the aliens from *The Voyage Home* liked them before whales showed up - then they had to largely rebuild their society from scratch on a new world once they arrived. Even a very slow technological advance could result in city-ships after that long.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Well the Voth are socially stuck. And think of how they treat scientists if they say the wrong things... I don't see such a society progressing fast. It's like having the Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith sit right in your collider tube.

Comment: @Einer They picked up the Doctrine after they have assembled a new home planet.

Comment: @Hexcept JamesSheridan found it to be odd that they had warp drive 66 million years ago and than stopped developing further. They might have stopped when they arrived at the planet because of the doctrine. Thats what I meant to say.

Comment: @Einer Ah sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Einer: That is certainly possible. The main problem with this argument - or any argument about the Voth, for that matter - is the sheer length of time they would have to remain in that state. 66 million years is a ridiculously huge amount of time. It's far more believable that they built a generation ship, then had to start from scratch, but even that leaves a huge gap in time.

Comment: It seems self-evident that the Doctrine wasn't in place when the Voth were in the Alpha Quadrant, given that the Doctrine states the Voth did not originate in the Alpha Quadrant.